# how can I connect the .live() to jquery ui tabs`s div

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, jquery

I use jQuery UI tabs().
I write the code like this..
First, I made tabs using for(){}. And I connected .live() to tabs`div.
But the problem is that only first tab`s click event is operating, 
the other tabs`s click event is not working.
How can I connect .live() or .bind()? Help me please.
**HTML code**

```
<div class="MYTABS" id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <% for(int i=0, n=scheduleList.size();i<n;i++){%>
                <li><a href="#fragment<%=i%>"><span><%=scheduleList.get(i).getName()%></span></a></li>
            <%}%>
        </ul>

        <% for(int i=0, n=scheduleList.size();i<n;i++){%>
            <div class="TABCONTENT" id="fragment<%=i%>"><%=scheduleList.get(i).getName()%>
                <div class="OFFTIME"><span>CURRENT TIME : </span><%=scheduleList.get(i).getOffTime()%></div>
                <div class="PLUS"><img id="year_Plus" src="../img/schedule/date_plus.png"/></div>
                <div class="TIME"><img src="../img/schedule/date_middle.png"/></div>
                <div class="MINUS"><img id="year_Minus" src="../img/schedule/date_minus.png"/></div>
                <img class="AMPM" id="am" src="../img/schedule/date_am.png"  onclick="toggleAmPm(this.id);"/>
                <img class="SETBTN" src="../img/schedule/btn_set.png" onclick="saveOffTime();"/>

                <div class="TIMETEXT" id="yearText" ><%=yyYear%></div>
                <div class="TIMETEXT" id="monthText"><%=zeroMonth %></div>
                <div class="TIMETEXT" id="dayText"><%=zeroDay %></div>
                <div class="TIMETEXT" id="hourText"><%=zeroHour %></div>
                <div class="TIMETEXT" id="minuteText"><%=zeroMinute %></div>
            </div>
        <%}%>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
// make tabs
var tabOption = {
    select: function(event, ui){
          //alert("");
     }
};
var usageTabs = jQuery("#tabs").tabs(tabOption);

// click event
jQuery(".PLUS>img, .MINUS>img").on("click", function(){
    var clickedTime = this.id.split("_");

    // plus and minus
    var timeText = jQuery("#"+clickedTime[0]+"Text");
    var calcTime = "";
    if(clickedTime[1] === "Plus"){
        calcTime = parseInt(timeText.text(),10) + 1 ;
    }else{
        calcTime = parseInt(timeText.text(),10) - 1 ;
    }

    jQuery(timeText.text(calcTime));
});
```

Comment: .live is being deprecated so use .on instead.

Comment: I had used .on() but there is same problem. Because I`m a beginner....I think my code has problem of div's Id.

Comment: Is that your entire JS code? Wait for dom ready before calling tabs or binding to the click event. `$(document).ready({ /* YOUR CODE HERE */ });`

Comment: I edit the question code of click event function

Comment: I solved this problem. I edited the div`s id like <div class="YEARTEXT" id="yearText_<%=i %>" ><%=yyYear%></div>. So the code  works correctly! Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Load #second after #main :)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#main" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            success: function( xhr, status ) {
                $("#second").tabs();
            }

        }
    });

});
```